# Will koalas eat pre-plucked eucalyptus leaves?

Tags: zoology, intelligence

Various [sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5diQgv20ewg) [online](https://www.ranker.com/list/koalas-are-terrifying-brutal-hateful-animals/justin-andress?page=2) (including a frequent [copy-pasta](https://www.reddit.com/r/copypasta/comments/5u1l9x/koalas_are_terrible_animals/) disparaging the animal) claim that koalas will not recognize eucalyptus leaves as food if they are cleanly laid out on a table in front of them, instead of attached to a tree.

- [University of Melbourne Scientific Scribbles Blog](https://blogs.unimelb.edu.au/sciencecommunication/2017/09/17/koalas-not-the-smartest-tool-in-the-shed/)

  > If you gather a bunch of Eucalyptus leaves, which the koalas eat, and put them on a plate in front of the koala, the koala won’t know what to do with them; they just sit there and gawk at it.
  >
  > They lack the ability to discern that it’s still food given that the leaves have moved off the tree and onto a new source that they’re unfamiliar with.

I know that they have a very small, unwrinkled brain, but what source is there regarding this peculiar dietary behavior?

Comment: @Feryll: I am not sure this dietary behaviour is that "peculiar". I recall a caged cockatoo that loved to be given a whole almond, which it would shell with its beak to get to the nut to eat, but when handed an pre-shelled almond nut, would discard it with disinterest.

Comment: This claim is presented in the textbook [Life of Marsupials](https://books.google.com/books?id=KqtlPZJ9y8EC&pg=PA234#v=onepage&q&f=false) from 2005, but I don't know what their source is either.

Comment: This is a comment since I have no source but myself.  Yes, I've seen a koala pull eucalyptus leaves off a kiddie plate placed out for it at a conservation park near Adelaide, Australia.  It approached, slowly took the leaves and ate them.

Comment: I just asked this question in pets.se and something that i think has bearing is that there is a video of a koala drinking water from a bottle -- but their name means "doesn't drink." If they have enough behavioral flexibility to drink water this implies to me that they might also be flexible enough to eat picked leaves.